# What is cost of EBS for 200GB max volume size or data stored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

If I create AWS EBS with 200GB max volume with data of 50 GB, so what will be costing criteria total max-size i.e 200 GB or for data stored like 50GB.

I am trying to understand for EBS General Purpose SSD (gp2) Volumes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be charged for full 200 GB storage no matter how much you use it.

Comment: To clarify... The [EBS pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) says "per GB-month of provisioned storage". **Provisioned storage** means the full size of the volume that was defined when the volume was created.